# Lenovo Thinkpad L430 Mousepad trackpoint not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad L430 under dual boot with Windows 7. But I find that its mouse pointer keeps vibrating and disappears many times. Also, its touchpad two-finger-scroll is not working. With Ubuntu 12.10, it was working fine.

Plz help. Thanks